# Custom Facebook login in swift

Tags: facebook, swift, xcode6

I have implemented custom Facebook using swift and when login is attempted it crashes with the below message 
"FbNewLoginSession]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
IBAction func fbNewSessionLogin(sender: UIButton!) {

    if (FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.Open || FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.OpenTokenExtended){
        FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
    }
    else{

        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], allowLoginUI: false, completionHandler: { (session:FBSession!, state: FBSessionState, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
        })
    }

}

func sessionStateChanged(session: FBSession, state: FBSessionState, error: NSError?){

    if error != nil {

        println("Error")
        FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
    }
    else{

        if state == FBSessionState.Open {

            //Fetch user details from Facebook
            FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({ (conection: FBRequestConnection!, userData: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if((error) != nil){
                    println(userData.name)
                }
                else{
                    println("Oops! An error has occured")
                }
            })

        }
    }

    if (state == FBSessionState.Closed || state == FBSessionState.ClosedLoginFailed){
        println("Session closed")
    }
    if (FBErrorUtility.shouldNotifyUserForError(error) == true){
        println("Something went wrong")
    }
    else{
        if (FBErrorUtility.errorCategoryForError(error) == FBErrorCategory.UserCancelled){
            println("User cancelled login")
        }
        else if (FBErrorUtility.errorCategoryForError(error) == FBErrorCategory.AuthenticationReopenSession){
            println("Current session is no valid")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert in debugging but still tried my best. The code just does not cross the first if statement. I'm pretty much new to swift. Help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is not as clear and specific as it could be. You tell us it "just does not cross the if" statement, and you have around 5 or more of those. You also talk about a "FbNewLoginSession", and I'm not sure if it is intentional or not, but that symbol doesn't exist at all in the snippet you provided.

Comment: Sorry to be more specific it enters the FbNewLoginSession action but it crashes at the first If statement itself throwing "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Comment: Is the "FbNewLoginSession" a class implemented by you? Does a part of your code call it? If so, can you show where? Do you have a line number from where it is failing? The current information provided is not enough to debug this issue.

Comment: @Flaxfield "fbNewLoginSession" is an action that I had created to respond to a button click. The app terminates the right before `if (FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.Open || FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.OpenTokenExtended){` but any statement placed before that gets executed. Please let me know if there is anything more you need. Also I apologise for the shabby question.